# How To Find Out How Many Zero Present And Display The Zero In SQL Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

SQL Query For Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(ID int,
 Value1 int,
 Value2 int,
)
```

SQL Query For Insert Value

```
  INSERT INTO Test
  VALUES(001,200,300)
```

OutPut

```
ID    Value1    Value2
1     200       300
```

Query To Display 00 In Result

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CAST([ID] AS varchar(5)) , 3),Value1,Value2
FROM Test
```

Now The Output Is

```
001 200   300
```

My Id Value Is maximum 5 Digit

Example 00001,00010,00100,01000,10000

Now i Want To Display The Result Like

```
   00001,00010,00100,01000,10000
```

I Need A Query Automatically Find Out How Many Zero Present Before The Number

Example 00001 This Value Have 4zero , 00010 This Value Have 3 Zero.

How To Use  This Query

```
 SELECT RIGHT('00' + CAST([ID] AS varchar(5)) , 3),Value1,Value2
 FROM Test
```

For Find Out How Many Zero Present And Display The Result With zero

Comment: `001` isn't a valid int. So you can't put `001`into an integer column.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do. '001' is a string, not a number. If you want to format 1 as '001' for display purposes, you can do it with the proper SQL statement

Comment: @Liam I Wrongly Add Question Before Now I Changed Plz Tell Me The Solution

Comment: @Gurunathan, you should add a new question.

Comment: @Liam my Account Is Locked To Ask New question So Plz provide Me Any Solution

Comment: whoops, someone's been asking some bad questions. Read the info on [question bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: @Gurunathan, BTW, looking at your account, you don't tend to accept answers very often. If you accept some good answers this might give you enough rep to get over the ban...maybe?

Comment: @Liam I Try And Then i Tell

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44779/discussion-between-gurunathan-and-liam)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numeric data types don't contain leading zeros. If you need to store leading zeros, you need to use a character datatype.

If you do that, however, to store numbers without leading zeros, please note that sorting on a character datatype field is done lexicographically, so you might end up with something like this:

```
1
10
11
2
20
21
```

Also, you should note the difference between data storage and data display. You could well store numbers without leading zeros, but make your application display them containing leading zeros!

---

As other people have noted, something like

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Field), 3)
```

will help you select the content of a numeric field as a string with leading zeros.

You could also do that in C# using

```
String.Format("{0:d3}", fieldvalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are basically saying "I want to store a non-integer value in an integer column, how do I do that?"

Now, the obvious answer is of course: you don't.

The *real* question is, why do you think you want this? If (as I suspect) it is for later display purposes, then forget about inserting invalid data and focus on the real issue: how do I *display* my data the way I want to?

And the answer to that is simply": anywhere but in your database :)

You can change your integer to a string before displaying, either in your `select` statement, or further on in your front end.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to format the number manually.  One way to do that:

```
select  right('00' + cast(ID as varchar(3)),3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CAST([ID] AS varchar(5)) , 3)
FROM test
```

The 3 is the number of characters you want total in the output display

Comment: Your Solution Is Help Full For Me But I Need Some Functionality I Edited My Code now Plz Check

Answer (score 0):

First you can't insert the value `00002` or anything like that with zeros (only in int type)... so the concept is fully wrong... or else change your data type to varchar then you can do these things...

if you are using varchar then simply use the following function

```
reverse()
```